# Scaling Images for multiple android devices efficiently : best approach

Tags: android, image, scaling, resolutions

I have images of size 1080P , now i do not want to use different variations of images that we put in RES folder . I am going to install this app on 1K devices with random images , so thats not feasible to have different versions of images.

Can we scale it on runtime , still getting the best quality ?

Answer (score 2):

To scale images use following

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.app_bg);
scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
```

then assign this `scaledBitmap` to any `ImageView` or any other `View`. This will scale the original `Bitmap` to the requested `width` and `height`. To get width and height of the device screen use following

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

**EDIT**
In order to handle `MemoryLeakException` add `scaledBitmap.recycle()` after using this `Bitmap`.